# Installing ffmpeg-devel with MacPorts fails

Tags: ffmpeg, macports

I did a selfupdate and updated all dependencies.

When I do

```
sudo port install ffmpeg-devel
```

I get

```
--->  Computing dependencies for ffmpeg-devel
--->  Building ffmpeg-devel
Error: org.macports.build for port ffmpeg-devel returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port ffmpeg-devel for details:
```

Here are the contents of the log file:
http://pastebin.com/pvUsU0fc

Most relevant entries from the end:

```
...
libavfilter/vsrc_mptestsrc.o libavfilter/vsrc_testsrc.o libavfilter/x86/gradfun.o libavfilter/x86/yadif.o 
:info:build libswscale/x86/rgb2rgb_template.c: In function ‘rgb15tobgr24_MMX’:
:info:build libswscale/x86/rgb2rgb_template.c:814: error: can't find a register in class ‘GENERAL_REGS’ while reloading ‘asm’
:info:build libswscale/x86/rgb2rgb_template.c:811: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
:info:build libswscale/x86/rgb2rgb_template.c:814: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
:info:build libswscale/x86/rgb2rgb_template.c:879: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
:info:build gmake: *** [libswscale/x86/rgb2rgb.o] Error 1
:info:build gmake: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
:info:build ranlib libavfilter/libavfilter.a
:info:build gmake: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_multimedia_ffmpeg-devel/ffmpeg-devel/work/ffmpeg-d3d5e84-i386'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_multimedia_ffmpeg-devel/ffmpeg-devel/work/ffmpeg-d3d5e84-i386" && /opt/local/bin/gmake -j4 -w all 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build org.macports.build for port ffmpeg-devel returned: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: NONE
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
```

Comment: Can you put h log here rather than an external site

Comment: @Mark The log is quite long, but I added the most relevant parts here. FFish, this is probably something you might just want to report as a bug to MacPorts, including all relevant information (version of MacPorts, OS X, build tools, et cetera): https://trac.macports.org/report